# Oracle 11g: Replace part of string using dictionary mapping

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

Is there any nice trick to change values in string using dictionary mapping? For example I have `table1` [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0a21/4/0)

```
+---------------------------+
|          ROW1             |
+---------------------------+
| This is an example string |
| This String has typ0s     |
+---------------------------+
```

And some mapping table `dict1` [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0a21/4/0):

```
+-------------------------+
|     OLD    |    NEW     |
+-------------------------+
| THIS       | THAT       |
| IS         | ARE        |
| EXAMPLE    | SOURCE     |
| STRING     | NUMBER     |
+------------+------------+
```

I need some `SELECT` statement that will split values in `table1.row1` and change words using mapping dictionary `dict1` so received values will be ( changing no existing dictionary values to upper is optional):

```
+---------------------------+
|      TRANS_ROW1           |
+---------------------------+
| THAT ARE AN SOURCE NUMBER |
| THAT NUMBER HAS TYP0S     |
+---------------------------+
```

PS. Spliting using REGEXP expression will be so nice..

Comment: do you mind PLSQL in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH dict1 AS
 (SELECT 'THIS' fr,
         'THAT' t
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'IS' fr,
         'ARE' t
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'EXAMPLE' fr,
         'SOURCE' t
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'STRING' fr,
         'NUMBER' t
    FROM dual),
table1 AS
 (SELECT 'This is an example string' AS str,
         1 AS sn
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'This String has typ0s' AS str,
         2 sn
    FROM dual),
src AS
 (SELECT regexp_substr(upper(s.str), '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) str2,
         s.*,
         rownum nn
    FROM table1 s
  CONNECT BY instr(TRIM(' ' FROM str), ' ', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
         AND PRIOR sn = sn
         AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL),
repl AS
 (SELECT nvl2(dict1.t, dict1.t, src.str2) lex,
         sn,
         nn
    FROM src
    LEFT JOIN dict1
      ON dict1.fr = src.str2)
SELECT listagg(lex, ' ') within GROUP(ORDER BY nn),
       sn
  FROM repl
 GROUP BY sn
```

It works now as you ask. Enjoy.

EDIT: [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0a21/10/0) with solution

Comment: Quite impressive.. but can You explain why You add `AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: in order to get rid of possible loops during parsing string. sometimes it happens when we have equal values in one string like 'oo bb oo'

Comment: according to your answer i modified my fiddle to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0a21/10/0

Comment: As I could see it returns what you what so I'm happy :)